# CFWheels - Issue with filters 'except'. Conflicting action names

Tags: model-view-controller, coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

I have a filter setup that runs a function which checks if the user session is present on certain actions, like so;

```
<cffunction name="init">

        <cfset filters(through="checkLogin", except="login,register,signin,create,home,profile") />

    </cffunction>
```

The problem is, these are the action names...which conflict from other controllers I have.

For example, I have 2 controllers 'user' and 'link'. Each of these has an action called create, so that my URL's are like so:

/user/create/
/link/create/

How can the filter know with which controller to associate it with? Is there a way to prefix certain 'actions' in the 'except' clause with the controller name too?

For example, maybe something like:

```
<cffunction name="init">

        <cfset filters(through="checkLogin", except="user/login,user/register,user/signin,link/create,main/home,user/profile") />

    </cffunction>
```

I remember trying this but it didn't work and borked.

Hope you understand what I'm saying here. I don't want to have to name every action in separate controllers totally unique names.

Thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use basic inheritance to accomplish this:

```
<!--- controllers/Controller.cfc --->
<cffunction name="init">
    <cfargument name="checkLoginExcept" type="string" required="false" default="">

    <cfset filters(through="checkLogin", except=arguments.checkLoginExcept)>
</cffunction>
```

Then in any child controller (`user`, for example), you can specify which actions to exclude. This works well because the parent controller should really know nothing about its children. It implements what it cares about and nothing else.

```
<!--- controllers/User.cfc --->
<cffunction name="init">
    <cfset super.init(checkLoginExcept="login,register,signIn,profile")>
</cffunction>
```

If another child *always* wants for `checkLogin` to run, then it shouldn't pass a value for `checkLoginExcept`:

```
<!--- controllers/Foo.cfc --->
<cffunction name="init">
    <cfset super.init()>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Thanks - this did exactly what I was looking for! I never thought about the whole inheritance aspect of the CFC's...a good tip right there.